# How to finish activity in OnBindViewHolder()

Tags: android

In my recycler view item I have a button so when user clicks on button user is going from one activity to another.
BUt when user is coming back from another activity and presses android back button then it backtracks activity on which recycler view is present.

Here is my code:

```
public class HomeBookAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeBookAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<LoadHomeBooks> list;
Context context;

public HomeBookAdapter(ArrayList<LoadHomeBooks> list,Context context){

    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public HomeBookAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_book_layout,viewGroup,false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final HomeBookAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    LoadHomeBooks model = list.get(i);

    final String bookId = model.getbUid();

    viewHolder.homeMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           Intent i = new Intent(context,BookDetail.class);
           i.putExtra("bId",bookId);
           context.startActivity(i);

        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    Button homeMore;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

    homeMore = itemView.findViewById(R.id.homeMore);

    }
  }
}
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,BookDetail.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Its still backtracking.

Comment: What you use when user come back from another activity!

Comment: I am using onBackPressed() method like this   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        Intent i = new Intent(BookDetail.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

Comment: No! Don't do that

Comment: What should I do please let me know.

Comment: If you have your own button then add `onBackPressed();` on your button click listner

Comment: No I dont have my own button, I am adding this method on android default back button available on devices.

Comment: Not need to start activity again

Comment: Not required `@Override public void onBackPressed() { super.onBackPressed(); Intent i = new Intent(BookDetail.this,MainActivity.class); startActivity(i); finish(); } `

Comment: Please remove this and then try again with `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`